# Leaflet clickable grid in polygon

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, geospatial, turfjs

I'm using leaflet.js to show reforestation efforts.

[image]

Is there any possibility to create a grid-pattern where every square of the pattern can be linked to a click-event?
Something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798494). 
It would need small squares that would together form a similar polygon as shown above.

I tried Leaflet-pattern, but the squares resize on zoom and there is no option to add an event to the pattern shapes.

Could I use the leaflet rectangle for this? How would I find the correct latitude and longitudes for each square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to [create a square grid](https://turfjs.org/docs/#squareGrid), then [calculate the intersection](https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) between each grid cell with each polygon.

It's up to you to decide the details of the square grid, and whether you want the same grid for all polygons, or a different grid for each polygon.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know Turf...I will give it a try next week

Comment: You can use desktop tools as well (I guess QGIS can perform these operations too), but the general concept of gridding the polygons should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Ivan Sanchez** I found the solution.
For anyone looking for it see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kristofvanwoensel/bqegv1p6/23/).

'''

```
    // initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
    var map = L.map(
      'map', {
        layers: [map]
      }
    ).setView([-5.0, 19.40], 11);

    //HexGrid
    var bbox = [19.35, -5, 19.5, -5.15];
    var cellSide = 1;
    var options = {
      units: 'kilometers'
    };
    var hexgrid = turf.hexGrid(bbox, cellSide, options);

    //Polygram that will contain the hexagons
    let poly1 = turf.polygon([
      [
        [19.4, -5],
        [19.5, -5.1],
        [19.4, -5.1],
        [19.4, -5]
      ]
    ]);

    _.each(hexgrid.features, function(hex) {
      var intersection = turf.intersect(poly1, hex.geometry);
      if (intersection) {
        hex.geometry = intersection.geometry;
      } else {
        hex.geometry = {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: []
        }
      }
    })


    L.geoJSON(hexgrid, {
      style: function(feature) {
        return {
          weight: 1
        };
      }
    }).addTo(map);
    L.geoJSON(poly1).addTo(map);
```

'''